# unable to print variable inside do loop in sap abap

Tags: abap

I am writing a simple program given as an assignment in sap abap workbench
to generate table using `do enddo` loop.
There I used variable m inside do loop which is declared as `m type i value 1`.
but its not getting printed please help.

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report  Z_BASIC_OUTPUT_PATTERN
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

REPORT  z_basic_output_pattern NO STANDARD PAGE HEADING LINE-COUNT
100(4).
DATA m  TYPE i VALUE 1 .
.
WRITE 40'student marksheet'.
WRITE 73'date:'.
WRITE /73'time:'.
SKIP 3 .
WRITE 10'student information :-'.
ULINE /10(19).
WRITE /10'student roll no.:'.
WRITE /10'student class   :'.
WRITE /10'student section :'.
WRITE /10'student name    :'.
SKIP 2.
ULINE 10(33).
WRITE /10'|'.
WRITE'subject details'.
WRITE 42'|'.
ULINE  /10(33).
WRITE /10'|'.
WRITE'sno.'.
WRITE 15'|'.
WRITE'subject'.
WRITE 24'|'.
WRITE'marks'.
WRITE 30'|'.
WRITE'grade'.
WRITE 42'|'.
ULINE /10(33).
DO 3 TIMES .
  WRITE /10 '|'.
  WRITE : m .
  WRITE 15'|'.
  IF sy-index = '1' .
    WRITE 'maths'.
  ELSEIF sy-index = '2'.
    WRITE 'science'.
  ELSE.
    WRITE 'english'.
  ENDIF.
  WRITE 24 '|'.
  WRITE 30 '|'.
  WRITE 42'|'.
  ULINE /10(33).
  m = m + 1.
ENDDO.
```

below is output ([output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScdPF.jpg) )

[image: output of the program]

Answer (score 0):

Lets look step by step what you do:

```
WRITE /10 '|'.
```

Write a bar at position 10,.

```
WRITE : m .
```

Write `m`. `m` is an integer and the output is 10 characters long (maybe I'm wrong, but it is longer then 5 characters). The number is aligned to the right. So on position 21 is now a number.

```
WRITE 15'|'.
```

No you go back on position 15 and start a new output. The next `write` command overwrites your number.

A possible solution: Restrict the length of the output:

```
WRITE : (4) m .
```

---

As recommended in the comments: If you replace `WRITE 15 '|'.` with `WRITE /15 '|'.` you get the following result:

[image]

You get a new line after the printout of the number and you see the number is at the same place as the subject text. In other words: Without the new line, the subject overwrites the number.

If you restrict the place for the number with `WRITE : (4) m .` you get the wanted solution:

[image]

---

Instead of writing and change always the position I woudl recommend to write the elements one after the other and each field gets it owns output length.

Example:

```
DATA: subject TYPE string.
DO 3 TIMES .
* Get the variable text
  CASE sy-index.
    WHEN '1'.
      subject = 'maths'.
    WHEN '2'.
      subject = 'science'.
    WHEN OTHERS.
      subject = 'english'.
  ENDCASE.
* And now the central output part:
  WRITE: /10 '|' NO-GAP,
        (3) m, '|',
        (6) subject, '|',
        (3) space, '|',
        (9) space, '|'.
  ULINE /10(33).
  m = m + 1.
ENDDO.
```

Remark: `space` is just an empty placeholder until you have the real data for the columns.

Comment: Can you replace `WRITE 15'|'.` with `WRITE /15 '|'.`? Then can you see if the number is printed and if there is another text on the same location.

Comment: if we replace 15 by  /15 then broken table will be drawn out put will not be proper .

Comment: Yes, but it makes it possible to identify the problem. The additional line break is not the solution, but a possibility to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the loop like this:

```
DO 3 TIMES .
 WRITE /10 '|'.
  WRITE 4: m .
  WRITE 15'|'.
  IF sy-index = '1' .
    WRITE 'maths'.
  ELSEIF sy-index = '2'.
    WRITE 'science'.
  ELSE.
    WRITE 'english'.
  ENDIF.
  WRITE 10 '|'.
  WRITE 24 '|'.
  WRITE 30 '|'.
  WRITE 42'|'.
  ULINE /10(33).
  m = m + 1.
ENDDO.
```

Apparently one line was overlapping the `m` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the space for m; if you write an integer, SAP reserves 10 spaces for the variable and writes it right-justified. That means the m variable is being overwritten by the science/math/english word.